# free-Jqgrid search modal drag stuck

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, free-jqgrid

As you can see in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7k4dv191/50/), when you open the Search modal, and try to DRAG it, it is "stuck"

```
var $grid = $('#grid1')
var data = [
    {'aaa':'ada', 'bbb':'bbbbbb', 'ccc':'cccscwce'},
    {'aaa':'ada', 'bbb':'bbbbbb', 'ccc':'cccscwce'},
    {'aaa':'ada', 'bbb':'bbbbbb', 'ccc':'cccscwce'},
    {'aaa':'ada', 'bbb':'bbbbbb', 'ccc':'cccscwce'},
]

$grid.jqGrid({
    localReader: {repeatitems:true},
    datatype: 'local',
    data: data,
    colModel: [
        {name:'aaa', label:'AAA', width:400},
        {name:'bbb', label:'BBB', width:400},
        {name:'ccc', label:'CCC', width:400},
    ],
    caption: 'TEST',
    pager: true,
    rownumbers: true,
})
.jqGrid('navGrid', {add: true, edit: false, del: false, search:true})
```

Can you tell me why? I don't think it's the jqgrid 4.13.6 version.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the bug in jQuery 1.11.0, which you use in combination with jQuery UI 1.11.4. Simple replacing of jQuery 1.11.0 to jQuery 1.11.3, for example, solves the problem.